# How to improve svg blur performance (in safari)?

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, svg-filters

I'm using feGaussianBlur on multiple spinning slotmachine reels to blur images. As the weels speed up, the stdDeviation is increased accordingly. This results in a very high CPU usage and laggs in the safari browser. Is there a way to improve performance? I read about css blur in some articles but they summarized, that the performance is the same.

Edit:
I tested css blur and the performance was even worse.

Answer (score 2):

Blur, by its nature, produces partially transparent results. These need to be blended with the background. In the context of an animation, this can lead to high performance costs. I can see three ways to counteract this. They all aim at ensuring the browser does not need to compute a pixel-by-pixel blending operation but can simply copy image buffers into the area of the animation:

1. Use blur on elements that sit on a completely transparent background. That means, no colors at all in any background layer. Admitedly, this is not a very realistic scenario.
2. Make sure there is no partially transparent object on top of the animated object.
3. If it is not needed outside the opaque area of an object, restrict the blur filter region to the object area.

The third one sounds as if it could be applicable to your problem.

If the area that is blurred is rectangular, you could change the filter region itself. As a default, filters are [computed for a region](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion) that goes 10% beyond the bounding box of the element it is applied to. To restrict this, set it differently:

```
<filter id="blur" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
</filter>
```

But if your element has a different outline, you would have to set a `clip-path` to make sure the filter remains invisible outside.

Both approaches could probably benefit from setting the CSS property `will-change: contents`. But be sure to [read the warnings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) about its usage: use it as a last resort, and use it sparingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test this on Monday and share my result afterward.

Comment: In my case neither changing the filter region nor adding will-change: contents had any effect on performance. I decided to remove blur for safari users, as the suggested approaches 1 and 2 also aren't suitable. But thank you very much for the detailed answer. It taught me something for the future!